# Innova 3320 multimeter calibration

Tags: multimeter, calibration

Anyone have experience adjusting the Voltage reading on these? My less expensive meters have a single pot for calibrating, but this one has three. Labeled on the circuit board as V1, V2, and V3. I'd be interested to find out what each of them does, but mainly, I need to know which adjusts the Voltage reading.

Thanks!

[image]

Update:
Thanks for the answers everyone! To answer some questions, I have a voltage reference that I like to keep my meters synced with. This one is a little off, and it bugs me. beyond that, I'm simply curious.  :)

Comment: Is it reading out of spec? What have you compared it against? If you need the level of accuracy typically implied by calibration, you probably need a multimeter with more than 3.5 digits from a recognized test equipment manufacturer which will come with a cal cert. (Basically, what I'm saying is that it's likely not worth the trouble.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VR1 is DC voltage adjust; VR2 is AC voltage adjust. Found by trial and error.

I have not been able to see any displayed value changes influenced by VR3 after tweaking it across all the settings.

Answer (score 1):

VR1 is voltage adjustment. Use a plastic screw driver.

Comment: Your answer will be more convincing if you can provide a reference or other supporting information.

Comment: And if you know about VR1 then how come you don't know about the other two?

Answer (score 1):

The [other answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/360909) is right, adjust VR1 with a tiny screwdriver. Clockwise is lower voltage and counter is increase. Tested using DCV function. You should use a voltage reference module, but I just used the readings from 2 other meters that seemed accurate and adjusted it likewise. The other 2 meters have a thousandths place, this 3320 only has 2 digits. And we don't know what the other 2 VR2 and VR3 are.